# Query OpenStack API for SR-IOV

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I'm trying to query my OpenStacks to figure out which has SR-IOV enabled, but cannot find anything the in APIs.

Answer (score 0):

there is no API at the moment that will show capabilities of SR-IOV